# Drop a part of file path while extracting from zip with gradle Copy/Sync

Tags: gradle

Given a zip file declared as a gradle dependency

```
dependencies {
    orientdb(group: "com.orientechnologies", name: "orientdb-community", version: orientdbVersion, ext: "zip")
}
```

which contains files in the following structure

```
.
└── orientdb-community-2.2.33
    ├── benchmarks
    │   ├── bench_memory_get.bat
    │   └── post.txt
    ├── bin
    │   ├── backup.sh
    ...
```

one can use the following task to sync the zip content into a given target directory preserving the complete structure of the zip:

```
task("deploy-db", type: Sync) {
    from(configurations.orientdb.collect { zipTree(it) })
    into(orientdbTgt)
}
```

How can I configure the above task to drop the `"orientdb-community-$orientdbVersion"` directory from the result so that the output is:

```
/${orientdbTgt}
 ├── benchmarks
 │   ├── bench_memory_get.bat
 │   └── post.txt
 ├── bin
 │   ├── backup.sh
 ...
```

Info: the `rename("(.*/)orientdb-community-$orientdbVersion/(.+)", '$1$2')` does not seem to work as it acts on file names only and the rename here concerns the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Gradle 4.5.1, the following is a reasonable facsimile which works.

It uses the `eachFile` ([doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Sync.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Sync:eachFile(groovy.lang.Closure))) feature on the `Sync` task. Below, we change the path on the `FileCopyDetails` object passed by `eachFile`.

```groovy
project.ext.orientdbTgt = 'staging'
project.ext.prefixDir = "orientdb-community-2.2.33${File.separator}"

task("deploy-db", type: Sync) {
    from(configurations.orientdb.collect { zipTree(it) })
    into(orientdbTgt)

    eachFile { fileCopyDetails ->
        def originalPath = fileCopyDetails.path
        fileCopyDetails.path = originalPath.replace(prefixDir, "")                   
    }

    doLast {
        ant.delete(dir: "${orientdbTgt}/${prefixDir}")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Funny enough I came to the same solution meanwhile except for the `doLast` bit: do you know why the original tree stays there empty, so why this `doLast` is needed?

Comment: Not sure why, but it seems reasonable to set up the folder before iterating over the files. Gradle is unlikely to confirm that all files were transformed to a new root.